# ¿Cómo manipular mi raspberry pi desde un servidor Laravel?

Tags: php, python, laravel, artisan

En mi computador de escritorio estoy realizando un proyecto en Laravel y quiero manipular mi raspberry pi de forma remota por medio del servidor, es decir, lograr que cuando en mi pagina web oprima un botón la raspberry pueda ejecutar un script que he desarrollado en Python. ¿Se puede hacer esto? ¿como lo logro?

Comment: Si, lo puedes hacer, aún que no queda claro como lo tienes y la pregunta esta incompleta. En mi caso tengo una RPi3 con un proyecto en laravel para controlar las luces de mi casa, pero el servidor web y proyecto laravel están corriendo directamente en la RPi3, y ejecuto los archivos python con el paquete de symfony Process  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage